# Setting a string in a body of httpResponse

Tags: java, servlets

I need help. In my current development one of the requirements says:

> The server will return 200-OK as a response(httpresponse).
>
> If the  panelist is  verified then as a result,  the server must also
>   return the panelist id of this panelist.
>
> The server will place the panelist id inside the body of the 200-OK
>   response in the following way:

```
<tdcp>

<cmd>

   <ack cmd=”Init”>

      <panelistid>3849303</panelistid>

   </ack>

</cmd>
```

Now I am able to put the httpresponse as

```
httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
```

And I can put

`String responseToClient= "<tdcp><cmd><ack  cmd=”Init”><panelistid>3849303</panelistid></ack></cmd></tdcp>";`

Now what does putting the above xml inside the body of 200-OK response mean and how can it be achieved?

Comment: @mattsmith5 The bounty should be on your own question, not on a completely unrelated one!

Answer (score 103, accepted):

You can write the XML directly to the response as follows:

This example uses a `ServletResponse.getWriter()`, which is a `PrintWriter` to write a String to the response.

```
String responseToClient= "<tdcp><cmd><ack cmd=”Init”><panelistid>3849303</panelistid></ack></cmd></tdcp>";

httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
httpServletResponse.getWriter().write(responseToClient);
httpServletResponse.getWriter().flush();
```

Comment: httpServletResponse.getWriter().close() is not a good idea. In general it's not a good idea to close a stream that was not opened by you.

Comment: This really helped, however, I didn't receive the body right away when using a JSON body. I had to add the following: httpServletResponse.setContentType("application/json");
httpServletResponse.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

Comment: yes httpServletResponse.getWriter().flush(); is better

Answer (score 14):

You simply need to get the output stream (or output writer) of the servlet response, and write to that. See [`ServletResponse.getOutputStream()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getOutputStream%28%29) and [`ServletResponse.getWriter()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getWriter%28%29) for more details.

(Or simply read any servlet tutorial - without the ability to include data in response bodies, servlets would be pretty useless :)

Answer (score 1):

If that's meant to be XML, Word has already spoiled things for you by changing the attribute quote symbol to `”` instead of `"`.

It is worth having a look at [JAXP](http://java.sun.com/webservices/reference/tutorials/jaxp/html/intro.html) if you want to generate XML using Java. Writing strings with `<` etc. in them won't scale and you'll run into problems with encodings of non-ASCII characters.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use a library or built-in functionality to escape the XML content properly before sending it in the response. This can ensure that any potentially harmful characters are correctly encoded.
2. You can also avoid directly concatenating user input to form XML responses, as this may lead to an injection attack.